# Efficient construction of a set of integer tuples

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computational-mathematics

I was wondering if there is an efficient construction for the elements of the
set

$$\left\{ x\in\mathbb{Z}^{d} \middle| \sum^{d}_{i=1}|x_i|\leq m \right\}$$

I guess a brute-force way of doing this would be by nested loops, but I was
wondering if there was something more elegant/faster.

Comment: It's hard to see how one could improve on the nested loops—that literally enumerates these $d$-tuples one by one with no computation.

Comment: Thanks!. I was wondering if something better could be done. For example, if I assume the integers are nonnegative, you can reduce the number of nested loops see for example (https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.2307/2986144).